# async / await: Continuously stream data from async method

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm using python 3.5 to asynchronously return data from one method to another as follows:

```
async def A():
    # Need to get data here from B continuously
    val = await B()

async def B():
    # Need to get data here from C continuously as they get generated inside while loop of method C
    data = await C()
    # Modify and process the data and return to A
    return await D(data)

async def C():
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        # Return this data to method B one by one, Not sure how to do this ??
        return i

async def D(val):
    # Do some processing of val and return it
    return val
```

I want to continuously stream data from method C and return it to method B, process each item as they are received and return it to method A.

One way is use an `asyncio queue` and pass it to method B from A, from where it further gets passed on to C.

1. Method C would keep writing the content in the queue.
2. Method B would read from queue, process the data and update the queue.
3. Method A reads the queue at the end for finally processed data.

Can we achieve it using coroutines or async method itself in any other way ? Wish to avoid calls for reading and writing to queues continuously for every request.

Comment: Probably `yield`? Not sure if it will help but...

Comment: Yes, you can upgrade to Python 3.6 and use asynchronous generators

Answer (score 3):

```
import asyncio
from async_generator import async_generator, yield_, yield_from_

async def fun(n):
    print("Finding %d-1" % n)
    await asyncio.sleep(n/2)
    result = n - 1
    print("%d - 1 = %d" % (n, result))
    return result


@async_generator
async def main(l):
    futures = [ fun(n) for n in l ]
    for i, future in enumerate(asyncio.as_completed(futures)):
        result = await future
        print("inside the main..")
        print(result)
        await yield_(result)

@async_generator
async def dealer():
    l = [2, 4, 6]
    gen = main(l)
    async for item in gen:
        print("inside the dealer....")
        await yield_(item)

async def dealer1():
    gen = dealer()
    async for item in gen:
        print("inside dealer 1")
        print(item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    #loop.run_until_complete(cc.main())
    loop.run_until_complete(dealer1())
    loop.close()
```

You have support for async generators in python3.6. If you are working with python 3.5 you may use async_generator library(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/async_generator/1.5)

Comment: Do you have a link to a resource that describes the async_generator decorator? I have never seen it.